# Load database content in more than one browser without refreshing

Tags: jquery, laravel

Am currently working on Hospital management system using Laravel 8 but I want to notify admin and doctor in charge about a New patient who needs consultation when the receptionist registers the patient. So here, I want the notification to go to their panels without refreshing the page and their tables to be reloaded. The same thing to happen to receptionist when requested to make payment for the patient by the doctor.

I can do all this in one browser that's the user who is handling the actions using yajra and jQuery.

**I WANT THIS TO ALL LOGGED IN USERS WITHOUT REFRESHING THE PAGE**

Thank you in advance and **HAPPY NEW YEAR**

Comment: you can do it using setinterval and ajax, or more realtime way is using websocket

Comment: You could implement this behavior with a WebSocket solution such as Laravel Livewire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have few options:

1. More easy, but more resource heavy. Do requests every 10 seconds to ping new notifications for user (patient or doctor).
2. A lot complicated, but resource frendly. Make use of socket. Disadvantage on this is that you will need some setup (socket server). I recommend this approach. Here is what i am talking about https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction.

Comment: Another possibility is to use Mercure: https://mercure.rocks/ ( repo: https://github.com/dunglas/mercure )

Comment: Thank you my dear. Let me try it with Websockets. I have seen something good in it. Thanks alot